# Javascript Array indexFirst

Tags: javascript, arrays

I build a prototype that handle pages, I successfully add (push), but can get the data, I failed:

```
var foundImageIndex = Pages.indexFirst(function (item) { if (item.PageID == PageID) return true; });
```

Here the javascript page handler:

```
var Pages = new Array();

PageContainer = function () //constructor for the proxy
{
   // this._baseURL = url;
};

PageContainer.prototype =
{

    AddPage: function (data) {
        if (data == null) return;
        Pages.push({ PageID: data.PageID, SegmentID: data.SegmentID });
    },

    GetPage: function (PageID) {
        alert('getPage('+PageID+')=' + JSON.stringify(Pages));

        var foundImageIndex = Pages.indexFirst(function (item) { if (item.PageID == PageID) return true; });

        var dt = { PageID: Pages[foundImageIndex].PageID, SegmentID: Pages[foundImageIndex].SegmentID };
        return dt;
    }


};
```

I call from other js as following:

```
var gPageContainer = new PageContainer();

 for (var i = 0; i < SegStruct.SegmentsCount; i++) {
                var segRClass = //get from webservice
                gPageContainer.AddPage({ PageID: i, SegmentID: segRClass.SegmentID });

            }
```

I trying to call: gPageContainer.GetPage(1); but it failed in  **GetPage: function (PageID)** it returns -1 in:
var foundImageIndex = Pages.indexFirst(function (item) { if (item.PageID == PageID) return true; });

foundImageIndex always -1

why?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Can you mention it somewhere in your question? Coz your code doesn't give a clear picture of your requirement. What is that `indexFirst` in your code? There is no such function in Array's prototype afaik

Comment: Also, add the `constructor` method to your `PageContainer.prototype` object.

Comment: the constructor is empty, the indexFirst is:if (typeof Array.prototype.indexFirst == 'undefined') {
    Array.prototype.indexFirst = function (validator) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.length - 1; i++) {
            if (validator(this[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
}

Comment: I want to manage pages, that include PageId which and segmentID, and want be able to get the data by passing the pageId

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following before the constructor:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.indexFirst == 'undefined') {
    Array.prototype.indexFirst = function (validator) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.length - 1; i++) {
            if (validator(this[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```